# Sorting a Lua table by key

Tags: sorting, lua, key, lua-table

I have gone through many questions and Google results but couldn't find the solution.

I am trying to sort a table using `table.sort` function in Lua but I can't figure out how to use it.

I have a table that has keys as random numeric values. I want to sort them in ascending order. I have gone through the Lua wiki page also but `table.sort` only works with the table values.

```
t = { [223]="asd", [23]="fgh", [543]="hjk", [7]="qwe" }
```

I want it like:

```
t = { [7]="qwe", [23]="fgh", [223]="asd", [543]="hjk" }
```

Comment: What problem are you really trying to solve?

Comment: Do not confuse a _table constructor_ (which has an ordered list of values with optional keys)—a source code concept—with an _actual table_ —a run-time data structure. The order in the table constructor is only relevant to the assignment of implicit keys.

Comment: Back to "What problem are you really trying to solve?" You seem to want to store or use more information/structure than you have in your code. Please explain the goal. It could be that you want an iterator. It could be that you want a different table structure. ….

Answer (score 28):

You cannot set the order in which the elements are retrieved from the hash (which is what your table is) using `pairs`. You need to get the keys from that table, sort the keys as its own table, and then use those sorted keys to retrieve the values from your original table:

```
local t = { [223]="asd", [23]="fgh", [543]="hjk", [7]="qwe" }
local tkeys = {}
-- populate the table that holds the keys
for k in pairs(t) do table.insert(tkeys, k) end
-- sort the keys
table.sort(tkeys)
-- use the keys to retrieve the values in the sorted order
for _, k in ipairs(tkeys) do print(k, t[k]) end
```

This will print

```
7   qwe
23  fgh
223 asd
543 hjk
```

Another option would be to provide your own iterator instead of `pairs` to iterate the table in the order you need, but the sorting of the keys may be simple enough for your needs.

Answer (score 6):

What was said by @lhf is true, your lua table holds its contents in whatever order the implementation finds feasible. However, if you want to print (or iterate over it) in a sorted manner, it is possible (so you can compare it element by element). To achieve this, you can do it in the following way

```
for key, value in orderedPairs(mytable) do
  print(string.format("%s:%s", key, value))
end
```

Unfortunately, orderedPairs is not provided as a part of lua, you can copy the implementation from [here](http://lua-users.org/wiki/SortedIteration) though.

Answer (score 3):

The [Lua sort docs](https://www.lua.org/pil/19.3.html) provide a good solution

```
local function pairsByKeys (t, f)
    local a = {}
    for n in pairs(t) do table.insert(a, n) end
    table.sort(a, f)
    local i = 0      -- iterator variable
    local iter = function ()   -- iterator function
        i = i + 1
        if a[i] == nil then return nil
        else return a[i], t[a[i]]
        end
    end
    return iter
end
```

Then you traverse the sorted structure

```
local t = { b=1, a=2, z=55, c=0, qa=53, x=8, d=7 }
for key,value in pairsByKeys(t) do
    print("  " .. tostring(key) .. "=" .. tostring(value))        
end
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no notion of order in Lua tables: they are just sets of key-value pairs.

The two tables below have exactly the same contents because they contain exactly the same pairs:

```
t = { [223] = "asd" ,[23] = "fgh",[543]="hjk",[7]="qwe"}
t = {[7]="qwe",[23] = "fgh",[223] = "asd" ,[543]="hjk"}
```

Comment: you are right but can we set keys it to ascending order because when i compare this two table it will out come as different because when i compare the first key value pair that will be t[223] and [7].if the both table are in ascending order then i can easily find the missing keys.

Comment: The manual [says](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-next): "The order in which the indices are enumerated is not specified, even for numeric indices." It may even change from one run  of the program to the other.

Comment: How is this an answer though? It's just "give up".